# How to add icon in list view Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

Is it possible add icon instead text in list view?

Example:

```
<field name="status" />

If status = phone display (icon="fa-phone) else status = fax display (icon="fa-fax).
```

Field display with string fax or phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change icon name.

Try with this:

```
<field name="status" invisible='1'/>
<button name="status" icon="fa-check text-success" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('status','=','phone')]}" />
<button name="status" icon="fa-times-circle text-danger" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('status','=','fax')]}" />
```

Comment: As this is a tree view, this would display the buttons in different columns.